# AWS Fargate Windows Container failing to start with : "The user name or password is incorrect.: unknown"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, windows-server

I am trying to run the barebones windows server core ltsc2019 on Fargate but I am getting the following error.
I have tested this with and with multiple variants of the same image but they both seem to fail with the same error.

I have also tried to set the OS platform to "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_FULL" and "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CORE" but this also made no difference.

```
Stopped | CannotStartContainerError: CannotStartContainerError: hcs::System::CreateProcess: C:\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc 69da9324ad914d8dbb35bdd2e91bd132-690230031: The user name or password is incorrect.: unknown
```

Task Definition:

```
{
"taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:347454123191:task-definition/TH-TeamCity-WIN-Agents-TCLXAgentTaskDefinition-vfqY9KUS25jX:1",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "teamcity-agent",
        "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019",
        "cpu": 0,
        "links": [],
        "portMappings": [],
        "essential": true,
        "entryPoint": [],
        "command": [],
        "environment": [],
        "environmentFiles": [],
        "mountPoints": [],
        "volumesFrom": [],
        "secrets": [],
        "user": "root",
        "dnsServers": [],
        "dnsSearchDomains": [],
        "extraHosts": [],
        "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
        "dockerLabels": {},
        "ulimits": [],
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-group": "TH-TeamCity-WIN-Agents-ECSLogGroup-QRfQsjAva3sk",
                "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "aws/ecs/teamcity-agent"
            },
            "secretOptions": []
        },
        "systemControls": []
    }
],
"family": "TH-TeamCity-WIN-Agents-TCLXAgentTaskDefinition-vfqY9KUS25jX",
"executionRoleArn": "redacted",
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"revision": 1,
"volumes": [],
"status": "ACTIVE",
"requiresAttributes": [
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
        "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
        "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
],
"placementConstraints": [],
"compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
],
"requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
],
"cpu": "4096",
"memory": "8192",
"runtimePlatform": {
    "operatingSystemFamily": "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_FULL"
},
"registeredAt": "2022-07-21T12:08:08.292Z",
"registeredBy": "redacted",
"tags": [
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons might be environment variables that must be passed to the container.
Can u check with the docker image which variables it needs to run the image.
U can pass the variables in task definitions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the image doesn't have a user named `root` and the task definition asks for the user `root`. I had the same issue just now. Removing the `user` setting fixed it.

```
{
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:347454123191:task-definition/TH-TeamCity-WIN-Agents-TCLXAgentTaskDefinition-vfqY9KUS25jX:1",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
        // ...
        "user": "root", // remove this
    }
  ]
}
```

You can probably create the user with something like the following, but I haven't tried that.

```
RUN New-LocalUser -Name "root" -NoPassword
```